# Hash Table - Unsuccessful search

Tags: hashtable

[image]

Anyone has any explanation about the part tow of the question the Unsuccessful search

I want to understand the Unsuccessful search in the hash table

why we have that answer and based on what  .

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the hash function is `h(x)`, and the destination that we want to insert to the hash table is `D`. The process of Linear Probing Hash is like the following:

1. Calculate the remainder `R` using the hash function `h(x)`.
2. Using `R` as the index of the hash table, insert `D` to the position of the hash table that `R` is indexing. For example, if `R` is 5, we will first check if the `ht[5]` is empty or not. (`ht` is the hash table. It is like an array).
3. If `ht[R]` is occupied, then we will check the index `R+1` and so on until we find an empty position.

#### So, the search process is like this:

We assume that the number we want to search for is `A`.

1. Calculate the remainder of `A` using hash function `h(x)`, then we get the remainder `RA`.
2. we first check the position 'ht[RA]', if the element in 'ht[RA]' equals to `A`, successed.
3. If not, then check the element at the position 'ht[RA+1]', until we find an element that equals `A`.
4. In the process that we increase `RA`, if we meet an element in the hash table whose remainder does not equal to `RA` or is empty, then the process ends, search is unsuccessful.

According to the above process, we could explain how the process in the picture goes.

The first number is 0. The remainder of 0 is 0. So, we first check the element at the position `ht[0]`. In the picture, the element at the position 0 is 9. So it is not the number we want. Then, we will check the next element, which is at the position 1. As we can see, the element is empty, so the search ends. It is an unsuccessful search because the number is not in the hash table.

The time that we use to search the number 0 is 2.

The expression in the picture should be understood like this:

0: 0, 1 The first 0 is the number we want to search, the following is the position we checked in the search process.

And there is another thing that we should notice:
In the search process of 8, 9, and 10, the hash table is like a cycle. If we reach the tail, then the next element we should check is at the head. In short, it is like this `ht[i % lens]`, where `lens` is the length of the hash table.